# Issue with the Azure storage javascript SDK preview 15

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-storage

The SDK seems to work correctly in edge and chrome, but in IE 11 I get

> This browser lacks typed array (Uint8Array) support which is required
>   by `buffer` v5.x. Use `buffer` v4.x if you require old browser
>   support.
>
> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'fill'
>   azure-storage.blob.js (29164,1)

What could be causing this?

Thanks for any information,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

In the preview version, **user need to import azure-storage.common.js first, and then azure-storage.blob.js. As browser doesn't support Buffer which exists in node.js**, and browserify helped to generate 'Buffer' which is suitable for browsers and put it in azure-storage.common.js.
In the coming GA version, considering together with modularizing and splitting support, we may put the common part into blob package, and this would help to solve such problem.

Source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/issues/402

Answer (score 0):

The library is compatible with IE11. Please make sure your IE11 doesn't enable compatibility view which drops the compatibility to IE10. IE10 doesn't have Uint8Array support.